# Error 500 internal server error in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing an asp.net application and am trying to make a post request using jquery ajax to web api2 controller method. Doing so results in error 500 internal server error.
Here is the jquery code

```
function reload(quantity, cartItemId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/user/UpdateCart",
            method: "POST",

            data: { quantity: quantity, cartItemId:cartItemId },
            success: function() {
              //  window.location.href = "/user/ViewCart";
            }

    });
    }

    function addItem(cartItemId) {
        var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt-box-" + cartItemId).value);
        quantity++;
        document.getElementById("txt-box-" + cartItemId).value = quantity;
        reload(quantity,cartItemId);
    }
```

In my web api 2 controller I have the following code

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateCart([FromBody]int quantity,[FromBody]int cartItemId)
    {
        var cartItemInDb = _unitOfWork.CartItemRepository.Read(cartItemId);
        cartItemInDb.Quantity = quantity;
        _unitOfWork.Complete();

        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: So what is the specific error? Where and when does it occur? Does the above code even throw the error. Your question is rather vague and probably unanswerable as it is now.

Comment: @VDWWD Forgive me I am new to asp.net.  How do I find the specific error? The debug window does not show anything

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code - put a breakpoint in and see when it turns green when you are stepping through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think webapi allows multiple frombody parameters. When I tried with your code, I got this error - "Can't bind multiple parameters ('quantity' and 'cartItemId') to the request's content.". When there are binding issues, your function will not be hit in visual studio as it will return from the pipeline itself.

Also, as per design too, you can have quantity and cartItemId and change your code as below:

Controller code:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/user/UpdateCart")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateCart([FromBody]CartDetails cartDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cartDetails.cartItemId);
        Console.WriteLine(cartDetails.quantity); // Your code instead of Console.WriteLine();

        return Ok();
    }
```

class:

```
public class CartDetails
{
    public int quantity;
    public int cartItemId;
}
```

ajax call in javascript:

```
        $.ajax({

        url: "http://localhost:49946/api/user/UpdateCart",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(
            {
                quantity: 12, cartItemId: 109
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("SUCESS: " + result);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error: " + data.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How were you able to see the specific error? Was it in visual studio debug window?

Comment: I was able to see the error in fiddler. It may not be possible to see this in visual studio since the controller code does not get hit. It breaks in the webapi pipeline before reaching the controller. in fiddler I was able to see it in the raw response.